# PHP Permissions: Trying to run a script when a web page is visited

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, permissions

I'm trying to build a sign-up workflow.  On the first page someone enters a bunch of information, then submits the form.  The processing script `/var/www/html/command/old/perl.php` needs to call a different script (`/home/ec2-user/perl.php`) which in turn calls a perl script.

From the command line I am able to run the `/var/www/html/command/old/perl.php` file (while logged in as `ec2-user`) without problem.  When I try to run it by visiting the script in my browser, however, I get a blank screen.

Here are the permissions on the two `perl.php` files:

```
[root@ip-172-31-30-184 old]# ls -l /home/ec2-user/perl.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nginx nginx 672 Oct 23 18:21 /home/ec2-user/perl.php
```

and

```
[root@ip-172-31-30-184 old]# ls -l /var/www/html/command/old/perl.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nginx nginx 94 Oct 23 18:24 /var/www/html/command/old/perl.php
```

the perl script itself (though I don't think it matters if the PHP scripts are working) has the following:

```
[root@ip-172-31-30-184 old]# ls -l /home/ec2-user/dnsmeapi.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nginx nginx 1605 Oct 23 02:02 /home/ec2-user/dnsmeapi.pl
```

What am I missing to make it work via the browser?

Comment: What are the permissions on the perl script?

Comment: I added them to the question, though if the PHP script can call it successfully while I'm SSH'd in (as ec2-user) I don't see why the perl script itself matters.

Comment: the perl script might be usable by nginx, but what about the containing directories? It's like a "free, take one" display inside a locked bank vault - useless/unreachable.

Comment: Your `ec2-user` permissions likely differ from those of `nginx`; check what Marc B mentioned.

Comment: I created a path in `/home/nginx/` and gave it permissions to the `nginx` user and group... same effects.